# Looping over distinct rows using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I have a sql table populated from a comma delimited notepad file. In the table I have 12 distinct column Value against the first columnA:

```
select distinct ColumnA
From Table
```

the values are A01, A02, A03 etc.

What I want to do is create a table dynamically using a loop in SSIS instead of doing it manually by

```
select * 
into A01
from Table
where col1 = 'A01'
```

Altogether there are over 20,000 rows of diffrent A01 - A12.

Whats the best way to go about doing this in SSIS? so each value i.e A01, A02 are populated into their own table?

Thank you

Comment: You don't need looping for this. In fact, loops are a very strong sign that you are doing something wrong. Just add a destination to `A01` and map the columns you want. Although it seems you need to unpivot your data first, possibly with the [Unpivot Transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141723.aspx).

Comment: PS, you may also want to look at the [Conditional Split Transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137886.aspx) which sends a row to one of several outputs based on criteria

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in SSIS, you can use the `Conditional Split transformation`, to send each row to a different output based on the value of `col1`.

As for creating tables dynamically, you will need to do that before the dataflow.   If you want to use a loop, you can use an `Execute SQL` task to get the distinct values of `col1`, loop through that record set, and execute another `Execute SQL` task that does a CREATE TABLE statement.

If you want to do this before you even import the notepad file to a table, you'll need to use a script task to read the file and generate the CREATE TABLE statements.

Comment: thank you but how would l loop over the distinct values and create the dynamic tables? Would I have to use variables? I just the most simple and efficient way of creating the tables based on the distinct values and populate it. Thats without having to use scripts etc

Comment: Yes, you would use variables.   The first ExecuteSQL would populate an object variable with a dataset of the distinct values, and the loop would populate a variable with CREATE TABLE statement that gets executed for each value.

Comment: Would I need to use the parameter mapping in execute sql task? I kinda get what you mean but i dont know how to implement it lol

Comment: No, you would need to make the variable contain the entire CREATE TABLE statement.